# Looping inside print()

Tags: python, printing

I have a dictionary that contains 9 items, it's called users. Now would it be possible to do this, which is completely functional:

```
for x in range (0, 9):
    print users[x]
```

In one line of code with something like

```
print users[x for x in range (0, 9)]
```

That gives syntax error. So is it possible to do it this way or maybe I need to use lambda functions or something? Thanks

Comment: Alright, seems like I didn't give you all the details, the users dictionary consist of 'id' and 'name'. What I'm trying to do is print the name property for each user, so something like this:
print (users[k]["name"] for k in range (0, 9))   
that gives me the <generator object <genexpr>> error

Answer (score 2):

Two notes before I come to the point:

First,

```
[x for x in whatever]
```

is totally redundant,

```
whatever
```

would yield the same indices.

In your case, it would be equivalent to

```
print users[range(0,9)]
```

which is the same as

```
print users[range(9)]
```

which won't work, because `users` doesn't support indexing with a `list`.

Second,

you shouldn't use a dictionary if your keys are integers that are consecutive and start at 0. That's a list.

---

What you can do is just use the different methods of a dictionary, e.g.

```
print users.items()
```

or

```
print users.keys()
```

or even

```
print "\n".join("key %s has value %s" % item for item in users.items())
```

if you want your code to look more like it was written in a functional language. Which Python is not. It has functional aspects. It's not always easiest to read when used in a functional matter. I would just stick with your original code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `print` inside loop, like this

```
for k in users:
    print (k)
```

or if you want to more flexibility you can use methods of `dict`, like `keys` or `values`, and you can do like this for more readble output:

```
for k in users:
    print (k : x[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can write:

```
print [users[k] for k in users.keys()]
```